# Difference between \the, \showthe and \show commands?

Tags: tex-core

I try to use these commands to print some geometrical parameters in my LaTeX source file to the terminal and the log file. However, sometimes there are problems after compilation with `pdftex` and it says that `Process exited with error(s)` in TeXstudio. Is this a problem since these commands are TeX primitives and it is really hard to fish for the output of these commands in the terminal or the log file, so is there an easier way to accomplish this task?

Comment: `\show` and `\showthe` share code with the error display procedures, so they “fool” the OS because when one of them is used, the error exit code is nonzero. Unfortunately, TeX only produces zero or nonzero, there's no way for setting different exit codes.

Comment: Related: [Using `\show` in `\nonstopmode` causes Texmaker to raise false alarms. Any fix?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142630/)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`\show` lets you see (in the log) what the definition of a control sequence is. If it is a macro, you get the definition, for others it tells how it is defined (e.g. whether it is a counter, token list, or length, etc.)
For a non-macro, `\the` typesets its value. And `\showthe` shows that value in the log file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newlength\somelength
\somelength=10pt
\show\somelength
\the\somelength
\showthe\somelength
\newcommand{\somemacro}[2]{this has #1 and #2}
\show\somemacro

\end{document}
```

In the log file you get three shows:

```
> \somelength=\skip43.
l.5 \show\somelength

> 10.0pt.

l.7 \showthe\somelength

> \somemacro=\long macro:
#1#2->this has #1 and #2.
l.9 \show\somemacro
```

and `\the\somelength` prints `10.0pt` in the output document.

Comment: By the way when I compile with it with `pdftex` using Texstudio it says process exited with errors when I use `\show` or `\showthe`. Why is it interpreted as an error?

Comment: If you run pdflatex interactively (from the command line), it will stop after each `\show`, so that you can examine its output. Then you have to hit ENTER to continue. Apparently TeXStudio interprets this as an error.

Comment: @Vesnog essentially `\show` is a user requested error with the error text showing the meaning, but it stops the tex run and allows the usual error prompts `x` to stop the run, `h` for more help etc.

Answer (score 22):

Basically, the difference between `\the` and `\showthe` is that the former inserts its result into the current token stream, for example among other material that TeX is typesetting, while the latter displays its result on the terminal (and in the transcript file) in the form of an error message.  See [The \the command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38674/69818) for a description of what these commands do.

The `\show` command is similar to `\showthe` in that it displays it results as an error message shown on the terminal, but, instead of returning the current value of some internal quantity, as `\showthe` does, it gives the current meaning of a token (typically a control sequence, but, as @egreg has remarked in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345185/difference-between-the-showthe-and-show-commands#comment847061_345188), `\show` works with any token).  In practice, the returned information is meaningful only if this token, or control sequence, represents a macro, in which case `\show` displays its current definition on the terminal.  When the token represent a TeX primitive, `\show` just informs you of this fact.

Let’s make an example that can shed some light on the difference: if you say

```
\show\parindent
```

TeX will answer with

```
> \parindent=\parindent.
```

which is its way of saying that `\parindent` is a primitive command (more exactly, in this case, it is a `<dimen parameter>`, see *The TeXbook*, p. 274).  On the other hand, if you ask for

```
\showthe\parindent
```

TeX might answer, for example

```
> 20.00003pt.
```

displaying the current value of the `\parindent` parameter.  And here’s an example of applying `\show` to a token that represents a macro: if you say

```
\show\mbox
```

you’ll get the answer

```
> \mbox=\long macro:
#1->\leavevmode \hbox {#1}.
```

It works in the same way for macro tokens that are not control sequences: for instance,

```
\show ~
```

causes the following reply

```
> ~=macro:
->\nobreakspace {}.
```

Last example: `\show` applied to a token that represents a primitive command:

```
\show x
```

yields

```
> the letter x.
```

showing that `x` is a primitive command that instructs TeX to add the character for the letter “x” (in the current font) to the current horizontal list.

A loose analogue of `\the` for the `\show` command is `\meaning`, that inserts into the current token stream (for example, into the text being typeset) essentially the same information that `\show` would display on the terminal.

It should also be noted that the `\the` operation is performed during token expansion (on the contrary, `\show` and `\showthe` are *commands* that are executed in TeX’s stomach), and that its result can be used for purposes quite different than typesetting, *e.g.*, they can be used to initialize a macro.  A typical idiom is

```
\edef\savedParindentValue{\the\parindent}
```

that saves the current value of `\parindent` for later use.

Comment: `\show~` and `\show x` are useful as well: `\show` stops processing and displays the meaning of the following *token*.

Comment: @egreg: Oh, obviously!  Answer updated: thanks for noting!

Answer (score 10):

As explained in the answers to [Using \show in nonstopmode causes TeXmaker to raise false alarms. Any fix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142630/using-show-in-nonstopmode-causes-texmaker-to-raise-false-alarms-any-fix), `\show` and `\showthe` interrupt TeX just in the same way as for errors (and they cause the process to exit with nonzero code).

If you want to record the value of some parameters in the log file and the terminal, the best is to use `\typeout`:

```
\newcommand{\recordvalue}[1]{%
  \typeout{%
    *** Vesnog message ***^^J%
    Value of \detokenize{#1}: \the#1^^J%
    ******%
  }%
}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\recordvalue}[1]{%
  \typeout{%
    *** Vesnog message ***^^J%
    Value of \detokenize{#1}: \the#1^^J%
    ******%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\recordvalue{\textwidth}

\recordvalue{\count0}

\recordvalue{\value{page}}

\end{document}
```

Output on the terminal:

```
*** Vesnog message ***
Value of \textwidth : 345.0pt
******
*** Vesnog message ***
Value of \count 0: 1
******
*** Vesnog message ***
Value of \value {page}: 1
******
```

Using a distinctive string makes it easier to find the information in the log file.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I think using a distinctive string is essential as the message is written among a lot of information.