# How to get the absolute value of \textwidth in Latex?

Tags: resize, textwidth, ieeeconf

I'm working with the [IEEE conference teamplate on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ieee-conference-template/grfzhhncsfqn), a two-collumn teamplate.
I used the tool Diagram to draw figure and now I'm exporting the figure to pdf and then will import to the paper like this:

```
\begin{figure*}[ht!]
 \centering   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/figure.pdf}
\end{figure*}
```

I know that with the option [width=\textwidth], the figure will be scaled to the width of current text. But with scaling, my figure seem to be a litte blur. Because the original width is different from the absolute value of \textwidth.
My question is **what is the absolute value** of \textwidth? Or how to print it out in latex code?

Here, Diagram allows to export figure to the expected size, I'm not sure about the unit but I think 1346 here means 1346 pt:
[image]

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article}  \begin{document}  \the\textwidth  \end{document}`.

Comment: Note: `\the\textwidth` shows the width in pt=1/72.27". You can use [package `printlen`](https://ctan.org/pkg/printlen) to print in another unit, e.g., in bp=1/72" (usually used by other applications as point size).

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to do here? What exactly did you create that you want to insert? And if it is a diagram, why is is not vector graphics? (aka resolution does not matter)

Comment: Also related: [Difference between \the, \showthe and \show commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345185/difference-between-the-showthe-and-show-commands).

Comment: note `\begin{figure*}[ht!]` is wrong, `figure*` does not  have an `h` option, probably it should be `\begin{figure*}` so you also allow the figure to be full page.

Comment: If the figure seem blurred is because the PDF have not a vectorial draw, but a bitmap image like JPG photographs with not enough resolution (<300 ppp or so) or maybe is only an effect of the pdf viewer.  Zoom at 400% or so. If it it is a vectorial draw, any part will look big, but perfect. If it is a bitmap, you will see the image clearly pixelated, and then the only solution is use a vectorial image or a bitmap with much more pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the software produces a bitmap image although wrapping it in a PDF file, so scaling is not the best approach.

Since the `IEEEtran` class has a fixed value for `\textwidth`, you can see it by doing

```
\the\textwidth
```

in your document. This will print 516.0pt and all you need is to convert this into PostScript points: since there are 72.27pt in an inch, but only 72 PostScript points, you can compute with a calculator

```
>>> 516*72/72.27
514.07222914072229140722
```

and pass 514 for the width to the Diagram software. Then include your graphics with no scaling.