# No output PDF file produced while using \tl_show, \str_show, \int_show etc

Tags: pdftex, latex3

While compiling Latex source file

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_test_value_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_test_value_tl {It's~a~test~value}
\tl_show:N \l_test_value_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    It's an example.
\end{document}
```

I'm getting an error without any details

````
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error temp.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(temp.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
> \l_test_value_tl=It's a test value.
<recently read> }

l.6 \tl_show:N \l_test_value_tl

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on temp.log.```
````

But if comment out \tl_show macro

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_test_value_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_test_value_tl {It's~a~test~value}
%\tl_show:N \l_test_value_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    It's an example.
\end{document}
```

the file is compiled without any errors and pdf is produced

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -halt-on-error temp.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex.fmt)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(temp.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-01-04>
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pd
ftex.def)
No file temp.aux.
[1{C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}] (temp.aux
) )<C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on temp.pdf (1 page, 14234 bytes).
Transcript written on temp.log.
```

The same problem is for other simular macros \str_show, \int_show etc.

Is this expected behaviour or I'm doing something wrong? Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason of this error?

Comment: You've told TeX to halt if it shows any output requiring a reply (`--hale-on-error`)

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, without `-halt-on-error` pdf is produced. It seems I've figured out with pdflatex options not carefully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I've found what is the reason of the problem above and can answer my own question myself :-).

It turned out macros for output values of variables to a terminal and a log file (**\tl_show**, **\str_show**, **\int_show** etc) are implemented using TeX error message mechanism. It means that pdflatex (even without `-halt-on-error` option) still returns a non-zero exit code and any build utilite (latexmk) or IDE calling pdflatex will be notifying about a build error. For example in case of VSCode + LaTeX-Workshop it looks like below

[image]

More detail about it can read here [Using \show in nonstopmode causes TeXmaker to raise false alarms. Any fix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142630/using-show-in-nonstopmode-causes-texmaker-to-raise-false-alarms-any-fix). Here [How can I make TeX stop on the first error, but do not stop on \show (or \tl_show:n)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/621919/how-can-i-make-tex-stop-on-the-first-error-but-do-not-stop-on-show-or-tl-sho) is advised how to avoid such behaviour.

It seemed the most suitable way for me is a reimplementation of macros for output values of variables to terminal. After some effort I've got following package

```
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\ProvidesExplPackage{DebugTools}{}{}{}

\cs_new:Npn \__start_label: {
    [DEBUG~INFO]:[line= \int_use:N \inputlineno]:~
}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Functions for output debug info in terminal and log
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show:n #1 {
    \iow_term:e {#1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_sep: {
    \iow_term:n {----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_head:n #1 {
    \show_sep:
    \show:n {#1}
    \show_sep:
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_val:n #1 {
    \iow_term:e {\__start_label: #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_tl:N #1 {
    \iow_term:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \tl_use:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_str:N #1 {
    \iow_term:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \str_use:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_bool:N #1 {
    \iow_term:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \bool_to_str:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_int:N #1 {
    \iow_term:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \int_use:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_dim:N #1 {
    \iow_term:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \dim_use:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \show_clist:N #1 {
    \iow_term:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ {\clist_use:Nn #1 {,}}}
}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Functions for output debug info in log
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log:n #1 {
    \iow_log:e {#1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_sep: {
    \iow_log:n {----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_head:n #1 {
    \log_sep:
    \log:n {#1}
    \log_sep:
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_val:n #1 {
    \iow_log:e {\__start_label: #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_tl:N #1 {
    \iow_log:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \tl_use:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_str:N #1 {
    \iow_log:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \str_use:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_bool:N #1 {
    \iow_log:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \bool_to_str:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_int:N #1 {
    \iow_log:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \int_use:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_dim:N #1 {
    \iow_log:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ \dim_use:N #1}
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \log_clist:N #1 {
    \iow_log:e {\__start_label: \exp_not:N #1 =~ {\clist_use:Nn #1 {,}}}
}

\endinput
```

with demo LaTeX source file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{DebugTools}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N    \l_test_value_tl    \tl_set:Nn       \l_test_value_tl    {It's~a~test~value}
\str_new:N   \l_test_value_str   \str_set:Nn      \l_test_value_str   {It's~a~test~value}
\bool_new:N  \l_test_value_bool  \bool_set_true:N \l_test_value_bool
\int_new:N   \l_test_value_int   \int_set:Nn      \l_test_value_int   {101}
\dim_new:N   \l_test_value_dim   \dim_set:Nn      \l_test_value_dim   {-2.5pt}
\clist_new:N \l_test_value_clist \clist_set:Nn    \l_test_value_clist {a,b,3,c,5}

\show_head:n  {DEBUG~INFO~FOR~TERMINAL~AND~LOG}
\show_val:n   {It's~a~test~value}
\show_tl:N    \l_test_value_tl
\show_str:N   \l_test_value_str
\show_bool:N  \l_test_value_bool
\show_int:N   \l_test_value_int
\show_dim:N   \l_test_value_dim
\show_clist:N \l_test_value_clist
\show_sep:

\log_head:n  {DEBUG~INFO~FOR~LOG}
\log_val:n   {It's~a~test~value}
\log_tl:N    \l_test_value_tl
\log_str:N   \l_test_value_str
\log_bool:N  \l_test_value_bool
\log_int:N   \l_test_value_int
\log_dim:N   \l_test_value_dim
\log_clist:N \l_test_value_clist
\log_sep:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    It's an example.
\end{document}
```

Now it's compiled without any error notifications and looks fine for my aims

[image]

#### UPDATE

Answering the question in comments I'd like to explain more detail why standard `\..._show:N` and `\...log:N` are not good for me.

`\..._show:N` produces following output to a terminal and a log file

```
> \l_test_value_tl=It's a test value.
<recently read> }
                 
l.6 \tl_show:N \l_test_value_tl
```

and has next pros and cons:

**Pros**

- The output is enough detail and contains the line number to easy search of a place in a source file where was produced this output.

**Cons**

- The macro forces pdflatex to return a non-zero exit code what causes a build error notification in IDE.

`\..._log:N` produces following output only to a log file

```
> \l_test_value_tl=It's a test value.
```

and has next pros and cons:

**Pros**

- The macro doesn't cause a build error notification in IDE

**Cons**

- The output doesn't contain any line numbers.

Beside of this I prefer to use `\..._show:N` to see debug info in terminal output immediately instead of opening a log file each time after build (it's a bit annoyng).

So, I've reimplemented macros in order to achive following goals:

- to avoid any build error notifications in IDE for `\..._show:N`
- to make output format for `\..._show:N` and `\..._log:N` the same, which in addition to a variable and its value also would contain some label (to easy search of debug info in a build output) and a line number (to easy search of a place in a source file where was produced this debug info).

Comment: As you only want it in the log, what's wrong with `\..._log:N`?

Comment: @JosephWright I've updated my answer above in order to explain more detail why standard `\..._show:N` and `\..._log:N` are not good for me.